# Unable to resume activity Java lang *NPE

Tags: android, android-activity

I have some numbers in an `ArrayList`. When the Activity is resumed, I compare the values in the list with the content of a `TextView`, and if they equal I set the data (number) from the `ArrayList` to `EditText`, and I get NPE.

So far I'm trying this code:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    for (MenuInputClass mic2 : results) {
        TextView namamenu2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nama_menu2);
        String comp = namamenu2.getText().toString();               

        if (mic2.getNama_menu().equals(comp)) {
            String jml_exis=mic2.getJumlah_menu();                  
            int jml_exis_toint = Integer.parseInt(jml_exis);
            jumlahmenu.setText(String.valueOf(jml_exis_toint));
        }       

    }
}
```

My `MenuInputClass`:

```
public class MenuInputClass {

    private String nama_menu;
    private String jumlah_menu;

    public void setNama_menu(String nama_menu) {
       this.nama_menu=nama_menu;
    }

    public String getNama_menu() {
        return (nama_menu);
    }

    public void setJumlah_menu(String jumlah_menu) {
        this.jumlah_menu=jumlah_menu;
    }

    public String getJumlah_menu() {
        return (jumlah_menu);
    }
}
```

Logcat output:

```
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.aplikasipemesananmenu/com.example.aplikasipemesananmenu.Appetizer_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at com.example.aplikasipemesananmenu.Appetizer_Activity.onResume(Appetizer_Activity.java:231)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3858)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
11-12 21:42:56.618: E/AndroidRuntime(19586):    ... 12 more
```

`Appetizer_Activity` :

```
public class Appetizer_Activity extends Activity{   

    static final String URL = "http://nervousme.vacau.com/android/xml_menu.xml";
    static final String KEY_SONG2 = "result"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID2 = "id_menu";
    static final String KEY_NAMA_MENU2 = "nama_menu";
    static final String KEY_KETERANGAN_MENU2 = "keterangan_menu";
    static final String KEY_HARGA_MENU2 = "harga_menu";
    static final String KEY_BAHAN_MENU2 = "bahan";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL2 = "image";   
    final Context context = this;
    AdapterDetailMenu adapterdetailmenu;    
    Button submitorder;   
    public static ArrayList<MenuInputClass> results = new ArrayList<MenuInputClass>();
    public static ArrayAdapter<MenuInputClass> lelel;
    public static ArrayList<String> list_list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_pemesananmenu;
    public static ListView list_pemesanan; 
    public static EditText jumlahmenu;  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_view);

        ListView list_single_list_view=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_single);    
        list_pemesanan = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        submitorder=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitMenu);
        final Button plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        final Button minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
        jumlahmenu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtJumlahMenu);        

       final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element        
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG2);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID2));
            map.put(KEY_NAMA_MENU2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAMA_MENU2));
            map.put(KEY_KETERANGAN_MENU2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_KETERANGAN_MENU2));
            map.put(KEY_HARGA_MENU2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HARGA_MENU2));
            map.put(KEY_BAHAN_MENU2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BAHAN_MENU2));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL2, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL2));            
            songsList2.add(map);
        }     

        adapterdetailmenu=new AdapterDetailMenu(this, songsList2);        
        list_single_list_view.setAdapter(adapterdetailmenu);        
        adapter_pemesananmenu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list_list);       

        submitorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    MenuInputClass sr = new MenuInputClass();
                    TextView namamenu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nama_menu2);
                    String hehe = namamenu.getText().toString();
                    String hihi = jumlahmenu.getText().toString();
                    sr.setNama_menu(hehe);
                    sr.setJumlah_menu(hihi);
                    results.add(sr);
                    ListPemesanan_Activity.list_pemesanan.setAdapter(new AdapterListPemesananMenu(getApplicationContext(), results));           
                    Log.v("MYTAG", "results" + results);
                    Toast.makeText(Appetizer_Activity.this, "Berhasil di Tambahkan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
             });        
}
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        TextView namamenu2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nama_menu2);         
        String comp = namamenu2.getText().toString();   

        for(MenuInputClass mic2 : results) {    
            //int asd=results.indexOf(comp);
            if(mic2.getNama_menu().equals(comp))
            {                   
                String jml_exis=mic2.getJumlah_menu();                  
                int jml_exis_toint = Integer.parseInt(jml_exis);
                jumlahmenu.setText(String.valueOf(jml_exis_toint));
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

**layout screenshot to understand**

[image]

**emulator screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Please, mark line 231 of `Appetizer_Activity.java` (it will be inside `onResume()`)

Comment: How do you instantiate MenuInputClass?  Is getJumlah_menu() returning null?  Is getNama_menu() returning null?

Comment: The NPE is at line 231 in your activity.  That line is in your onResume().  Which line is it?

Comment: @Simon
line 231 : String comp = namamenu2.getText().toString();

Comment: Your TextView is coming back null from findViewById(). Ensure that setContentView() has been called *before* findViewById(), also be sure that a TextView with id:R.id.nama_menu2 exists in the layout you are passing to setContentView()

Comment: Beside `namamenu2` being `null`, you should compute `comp` outside of the loop because it doesn't depend on the current iteration, and please can you explain why you convert back and forth between strings and ints in your `if`? Can you also rephrase your question to explain exaclty what you do with your `List` and where it comes from? (BTW, I can't see any `ArrayList` in the provided sample...)

Comment: @Raffaele about convert back and forth the string, it's just my experiment to solve another problem..lol..i added whole Appetizer_Activity so you can look the 'List' came from..'ArrayList'(results) is added from namamenu(TextView) and jumlahmenu(TextView too), and i'am set this results to listview in another activity, so if in this listview has the same name,example :Rice, and i go to Appetizer_Activity which in this activity i added the data, so if in listview(another activity) has the same data(Rice) its loads the data and its number(jumlahmenu) and set it to EditText jumlahmenu.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the section of the documentation about [`AdapterView`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews). Generally speaking, you can't retrieve the views in an `AdapterView` by their IDs. Also, you **can't absolutely ever** access fields of other activities in that way (ie using a static field like `MyActivity.widget`).

The usual pattern for using `ListView` is:

1. Declare the `ListView` in your XML layout and give it an ID
2. Create a layout for the row
3. Retrieve the `ListView` by ID and set its adapter (usually in `onCreate()`)

When you need to communicate between activities, use the `Intent` framework ([guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)). You may need to override [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) in certain cases.

Comment: so what is your recomended solution for this case?

Comment: Redesign your code and follow the Android way. I cannot be more specific because your English is very bad (even worse than the code :P) and I wasn't even be able to understand what you want to accomplish exactly. I can only argue that things are wrong on the programming side, so eventually the business part will fail, too.